# Skew one side of image while keeping border-radius

Tags: html, css

TLDR; is this shape possible using vanilla CSS? tried skewing but it applies to the entire image and therefore rules out the "skew one side" part of the problem.

[image]

Comment: Worth looking into: [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

Comment: @DBS

clip-path doesn't honor border-radius, tried that road

Comment: You can build the border radius into the clipping, I've written and answer showing how but I'm trying to make it a bit more re-usable before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px 90px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(-19deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(-30deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(-30deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/4E0744CD-793A-4EF8-B550B54F7F2C4406_source.jpg">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Ping me if it works for you.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

With some extra wrapper it's doable:

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:25px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box div {
  border-radius:inherit;
  transform-origin:top;
  transform:skew(20deg);
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box div img {
  display:block;
  transform-origin:inherit;
  transform:skew(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/300/200" >
  </div>
</div>
```